# Callback на завершение процесса в subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, asyncio

Сервис запущен в *asyncio event_loop*, через **Popen** запускаются дочерние процессы. Как получить информацию, о том, что процесс завершился без опроса состояния по интервалу. Нужно решение возможностями **subprocess**.

Comment: у него похоже синхронный попен.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess` только если опрашивать в отдельном треде и синхронизировать ,например, семафором.

Если сервис на `asyncio`, то есть смысл поработать и ним.

Для калбэков рекомендую использовать [asyncio.SubprocessProtocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.SubprocessProtocol) для обработки подпроцессов в asyncio. Вместо popen теперь [loop.subprocess_exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.subprocess_exec)

Протокол реализуется таким образом(пример из документации):

```
import asyncio
import sys

class DateProtocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol):
    def __init__(self, exit_future):
        self.exit_future = exit_future
        self.output = bytearray()

    def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
        self.output.extend(data)

    def process_exited(self):
        self.exit_future.set_result(True)

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_date(loop):
    code = 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.now())'
    exit_future = asyncio.Future(loop=loop)

    # запускает питон с кодом
    # Create the subprocess controlled by the protocol DateProtocol,
    # redirect the standard output into a pipe
    create = loop.subprocess_exec(lambda: DateProtocol(exit_future),
                                  sys.executable, '-c', code,
                                  stdin=None, stderr=None)
    transport, protocol = yield from create

    # Wait for the subprocess exit using the process_exited() method
    # of the protocol
    yield from exit_future

    # Close the stdout pipe
    transport.close()

    # Read the output which was collected by the pipe_data_received()
    # method of the protocol
    data = bytes(protocol.output)
    return data.decode('ascii').rstrip()

if sys.platform == "win32":
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

date = loop.run_until_complete(get_date(loop))
print("Current date: %s" % date)
loop.close()
```

`exit_future` используется для индикации завершения процесса - блокирует до завершения процесса.

`process_exited` - нужный Вам калбак. Чтоб не опрашивать состояние, он выполнится по завершении процесса.

Comment: такие сложности совсем ни  к чему. В asyncio у дочернего процесса также есть communicate() метод. [Вот пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616229/4279). Так как не ясно, что конкретно у автора вопроса есть и что он хочет получить, то следовало бы вместо ответа, который не ясно на какой вопрос отвечает, оставить комментарий к вопросу оставить с просьбой уточнить и проголосовать о закрытии как "неясный вопрос", как я это сделал (сейчас комментарии удалены, по вашей просьбе).

Comment: Ответ на вопрос "как повесить калбак на попен?"

Comment: у вас в ответе нет `subprocess.Popen`. Если вы решили игнорировать одни требования в вопросе, но не другие (используя вероятно искусство чтения мысли, чтобы угадать, что автор действительно хочет: *"Нужно решение возможностями subprocess."*), то по крайней мере приводите адекватное решение для задачи, которую вы сами выбрали. Если ваша задача: прочитать, используя asyncio цикл, вывод из внешней команды, то следует начинать с самого простого метода, который работает (`communicate()`) и только если появятся дополнительные требования, тогда уже усложнять.

Comment: Некоторые требования не всегда выполнимы.
 
Ответ с 0 лучше чем отсутствие ответов.

Comment: усложнённый вариант в ответе вводит в заблуждение (так как есть проще решения, если мы самостоятельно требования выбираем). Лучше если нет ответа, чем тот ответ, который в заблуждение вводит.

Comment: В заблуждение не ввожу: именно так вешается калбэк в документации.
Решения проще возможно появятся рядом и я поставлю им плюсик.)

Comment: [ещё раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727327/callback-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-subprocess-popen/727371#comment1117953_727371)